# How can I load blob in iframe

Tags: mysql, node.js, fetch

I'm getting PDF files from MYSQL server data type with BLOB but can't get it to work, Please help

When user click on tree node on left hand side tree. I'm getting ID from that and it sends to backend to get BLOB file and it sends back to front.

But I can't not get it to work.

-----Front end document.ejs file------

```
<iframe id="fileViewer" src="/cleft.pdf" type="application/pdf" alt="Click left side pdf file" width="100%" height="100%" style="height: 60vh" ></iframe>
```

```
const file = {
                id : data.id,
                parent: data.parent,
                text: data.text,
                dftype:data.dftype
            };

fetch('/document/getDocument', {
                method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify(file),
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'ResponseType': 'blob'
                }
            }).then( res => {
                res.blob().then(function (data){
                var file = new Blob( [data], {type: 'application/pdf'} );
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
                $("#fileViewer").attr("src", fileURL);  
            });
});
```

--------Back end---------

```
router.post('/getDocument', (req, res) => {

  var doc = new Doctree();

  doc.GetDoc( req.body.id, req.body.parent).then( result => {

    res.send( result[0].file );
  })
});
```

```
GetDoc(id, parent) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

            var query = `SELECT * FROM hr_dftree WHERE id = ${id} and parent = ${parent}`;
            pool.getConnection( (err, connection) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
                    resolve(result);
                });
            })

        })
    }
```

I expect the PDF file to load on iframe tag, but when I run the code chrome says

```
Error
Failed to load PDF document.
```

Comment: If you do a window.open(fileURL), does it work? This will make sure that the iframe is truly the issue. Also, try to put in res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf').

Comment: I have tried with window.open(fileURL) but it gives me same error message. I will try to set the header with application/pdf and let you know. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't get any request from fetch call when I set the header to application/pdf
router.post('/getDocument', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello------->: ", req.body);
})
Output: Hello------->:  {}

Comment: I find solution to this problem.  Call the query simply convert blob to text.
select CONVERT(file USING utf8) file  from hr_dftree